# CURL Usage in making Api Call

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, curl

Can someone suggest me to make curl api call for these syntax

```
curl -u john.doe@mycompany.com:c14b85863755158d7aa5cc4ba17f61cb -H X-API-Version:2 https://api.livechatinc.com/agents
```

I tried to use this code but not succeed

```
$url = john.doe@mycompany.com:c14b85863755158d7aa5cc4ba17f61cb@https://api.livechatinc.com/offline_messages";
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<pre>';print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find [curl library](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl) for CodeIgniter framework here from the developer site itself. Load the library in your controller like below.

```
$this->load->spark('curl');
```

and make a simple call to your api using curl simple_get method like below and save the response in a variable. Use it based on how you are getting either JSON/XML.

```
$this->curl->simple_get('http://example.com/');
```

For [reference](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-curl) please visit this link.